# Xamarin Forms - Google map show multiple markers on map

Tags: c#, android, google-maps, xamarin.forms

I am using `Android.Gms.Maps.GoogleMap` to display a map in my Xamarin forms app android project. I can't find much documentation on displaying (ideally) a circle on the screen at a particular latitude and longitude, or (less ideally) a marker pin.

Is there a function such as `GoogleMap.addMarker(double latitude, double longitude)` or similar, to display such a circle or pin?

Comment: There is the `AddMarker(MarkerOptions)` method, see here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/maps_and_location/maps/part_2_-_maps_api/

Comment: Thanks Daniel, can't  believe I missed that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add circle on google map use this code:

```
Circle circle;
public void OnMapReady (GoogleMap googleMap)
  {
    map = googleMap;

    var circleOptions = new CircleOptions ();
    circleOptions.InvokeCenter (new LatLng (lat, lon));
    circleOptions.InvokeRadius (circle.Radius);
    circleOptions.InvokeFillColor (0X66FF0000);
    circleOptions.InvokeStrokeColor (0X66FF0000);
    circleOptions.InvokeStrokeWidth (1);
    circle = map.AddCircle (circleOptions);
  }
```

To add marker use this:

```
Marker marker;
public void OnMapReady (GoogleMap googleMap)
{
 MarkerOptions markerOpt1 = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOpt1.SetPosition(new LatLng(lat, lon));
    markerOpt1.SetTitle("testing");
    marker = googleMap.AddMarker(marker1);
}
```

To avoid multiple marker and circle you can edit their position without making a new one:

```
 circle.Center = new LatLng(latLng.Latitude, latLng.Longitude);
 marker.Position = new LatLng(latLng.Latitude, latLng.Longitude);
```

Comment: Thanks Rai, this is a great answer

Comment: Xamarin Google Play Services Map, You can follow this reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/maps-and-location/maps/maps-api